# user defined URL style will not break onto the next line like in \url hyperref

Tags: formatting, hyperref, links, url

I am trying to get a URL link to break like when you use `\url` but I have defined my own as I wanted it to be underlined in a specific way but now it will not match the text width.

This is my code:

```
%add underline- above the hanging letters but with white buffer to break line betweeen hanging letters
\usepackage{contour}

\usepackage{ulem}   %underline, can choose many types
\usepackage{xcolor}            % specify colors by name (e.g. "red")
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %load clickable urls


\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=black,
}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt} %to make underline above text and have outline to make it seem like gap
\contourlength{0.8pt}
\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
\uline{\phantom{#1}}%
\llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}

% hack into hyperref- to have blue and underline
\makeatletter
\DeclareUrlCommand\ULurl@@{%
\def\Url{\myuline}}%
\def\UrlFont{\computermodern\color{blue}}%
\def\ULurl@#1{\hyper@linkurl{\ULurl@@{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\ULurl{\hyper@normalise\ULurl@}
\makeatother
```

Using the hypen break does not work as my actual link has no hypens. I don't like how it looks when I use `\sloppy`.
[image: url will not break]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Neither \phantom nor \llap will allow or trigger a linebreak.